# What's wrong with these MySQL column constraints?

Tags: mysql

I'm getting a syntax error when I try to create this column in MySQL 5.5.24:

```
`count` mediumint unsigned not null default=0
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Could you paste the whole query ? And also the error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `=` sign from `default = 0`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55533

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  `count` mediumint unsigned not null default 0
);
```

See the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

```
column_definition:
    data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks :) , but the book I am referring has an e.g. grade char(2) default='E1' , has the syntax changed?

Comment: Maybe the author of the book was tired when he wrote this, and he also didn't actually tried to execute what he wrote :)